# Creating SQL table where empty string on DATETIME or INT doesn't default

Tags: sql, datetime, default, sqldatatypes

How do I create a table so that an `INSERT INTO` with empty string doesn't default to Jan 1, 1900 for `DATETIME` data type, or 0 for `INT` data type?

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  TS DATETIME,
  VA INT
)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('','')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('','2')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('2012-06-08 12:13:14','')

SELECT * FROM TEST
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fafb/1)

Comment: You don't want the data type default, but what default do you want instead? NULL?

Comment: Empty ideally but I realize it's not possible during `INSERT`, but rather at `SELECT` using a `CONVERT()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to insert empty strings `''` for the DATETIME column.

Use `NULL` instead.

This will work if you define the column as NULL.

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (NULL,'')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (NULL,'2')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('2012-06-08 12:13:14','')
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize forcing the value to be empty can only be done at the `SELECT` level using a `CONVERT`

Answer (score 0):

this is Answer of your Question:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  TS DATETIME  NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  VA INT  NULL DEFAULT NULL
)

INSERT INTO TEST (VA) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO TEST (TS) VALUES ('2012-06-08 12:13:14')
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure some default value for columns while creating the table itself.
ex: Defaulting to null

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST
    (
      TS DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
      VA INT DEFAULT NULL
    )
```

This will store 0000:00:00 00:00:00 and '' as the values while inserting.